# My data type in MS Access is Date and Time my error is mis match data type

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

my data type in my database is date/time

my error is data type mis match

please help tnx...

```
            Dim try3 As String
            cmd1 = "SELECT count(new) AS cnew FROM sheet WHERE empname =  '" & try3 & "' AND new IS NOT NULL"
            cmd2 = "SELECT count(rev1) AS crev1 FROM sheet WHERE empname =  '" & try3 & "' AND rev1 <> '" & try2 & "' "
            cmd3 = "SELECT count(rev2) AS crev2 FROM sheet WHERE empname =  '" & try3 & "' AND rev2 <> '" & try2 & "' "
            cmd4 = "SELECT count(rev3) AS crev3 FROM sheet WHERE empname =  '" & try3 & "' AND rev3 <> '" & try2 & "' "
            cmd5 = "SELECT count(rev4) AS crev4 FROM sheet WHERE empname =  '" & try3 & "' AND rev4 <> '" & try2 & "' "
            cmd6 = "SELECT count(rev5) AS crev5 FROM sheet WHERE empname = '" & try3 & "' AND rev5 <> '" & try2 & "' "
```

Answer (score 0):

If `try2` is your date variable, it should read:

```
AND rev1 <> #" & try2.ToString("yyyy'/'mm'/'dd") & "# "
```